# Express JS what is the correct way to inject non-field property into Mongoose model before return it to client

Tags: express, mongoose

Using Mongoose model method `findOne`, I receive a model. Now I want to custom that model before sending it to client, augmenting several attributes into that model.

However, the only way I found for the moment is to turn that model into plain object and augment that object.

I don't know is there any better way doing it?

Here is my lengthy code for that simple purpose:

```
Topic.find({}).exec(function (err, topics) {
  var i, topic_obj, topic_obj_list;
  topic_obj_list = [];

  if (err) { return next(err); }

  for (i = 0; i < topics.length; i++) {
    topic_obj = topics[i].toObject();

    if (req.user.is_following) {
      topic_obj.is_following = true;
    } else {
      topic_obj.is_following = false;
    }

    topic_obj_list.push(topic_obj);
  }

  return res.json(200, topic_obj_list);
});
```

P/S: I already tried simple solution like: topics[i].is_following = true, bit it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can shorten it to something like this:

```
Topic.find({}).exec(function (err, topics) {
  if (err) { return next(err); }

  return res.json(topics.map(function(topic) {
    return topic.set(
      'is_following',
      req.user.is_following ? true : false,
      { strict : false }
    );
  }));
});
```

Explanation:

- `topics.map` runs a function on each item of the `topics` array; the value that is returned from the function ends up in the result returned by `map`;
- with `topic.set(FIELD, VALUE, [{ strict : false }])` you can add/overwrite fields of a Mongoose document; when `strict` is `false`, the field doesn't have to exist in the schema;